# How to prevent "xml:space="preserve"" generated by thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf working with spring boot.

The key part of thymeleaf dependency in my maven pom.xml are as below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in my HTML file, I put:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

at the top.

My goal is write some values from backend data to build javascript variables as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var roomProfile = {
            rid: 2,
            sig: [[${room.name}]]
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

but it always make the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var roomProfile = {
            rid: 2,
            sig: 'abcd'
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

How to remove the "xml:space="preserve"" from output?